# Exception Message not showing

Tags: c#, asp.net

my `checked==false` message and exception do not work.

here is the code :

```
 private void Submit()
    {
        if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd = new SqlCommand(@"INSERT INTO orders3
                            (order_custname,order_productname
                            ,order_address,order_tel#,order_cel#
                            ,order_cp,order_delivery,order_terms
                            ,order_file,order_qty,order_unit
                            ,order_jobdesc,order_verified1)
                            VALUES
                            (@custname,@productname
                            ,@address,@tel#,@cel#
                            ,@cp,@delivery,@terms
                            ,@file,@qty,@unit
                            ,@jdesc,@verified1)
                            ", con);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@custname", lblCustname.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@productname", DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value.ToString());

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel#", txtTel.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cel#", txtCel.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cp", txtcp.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@delivery", txtDelAr.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@terms", txtTerms.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@file", lblFile.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@qty", txtQty.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@unit", txtUnit.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@jdesc", txtJobDesc.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@verified1", "yes");

                string script1 = "alert(\"Your order has been submitted.\");";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                    "ServerControlScript", script1, true);
            }
            catch
            {

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
                string script = "alert(\"Please recheck your form.\");";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                    "ServerControlScript", script, true);
            }

            if (CheckBox1.Checked == false)
            {

                string script2 = "alert(\"Please Agree to our terms.\");";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                    "ServerControlScript", script2, true);

            }
        }
    }
```

Whenever the checked box is **true** I could submit the file.
But the problem is I'm also trying to get the exception whenever I leave a textbox empty. The first method I tried functions work whenever the `checkedbox == false` it doesn't send. With my new Class this time when `checkedbox == false` messagebox doesn't work either along with the **catch** message.

**edit1**
so my checkedbox==false message nows functions.my only problems is exception

Comment: You call `ExecuteNonQuery()` _inside your catch block_? Shouldn't that be in the `try` block? I can't see anything in the try block that would raise an exception for an empty textbox. The only "dangerous" thing is `ExecuteNonQuery`, so put that in your try block.

Comment: Seems there's a logical fault - `CheckBox1.Checked == false` is resided in 'CheckBox1.Checked == true` condition?

Comment: what's inside my catch block then?`con.close`

Comment: And you seem to tell the user "Your order has been submitted." before you call `ExecuteNonQuery`, so _before_ it really has been submitted.

Comment: The `catch` block is there to _catch_ an exception that was thrown in the `try` block. You do error handling in a catch block, like logging that exception message and stack trace and informing the user about the error. Please refer to a c# basics book or google "c# try catch".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, I wouldn't execute a query in the `catch` statement. Also if you want to see what error did occur, you'll need to use something like below.

```
try
{
    // sql code
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
finally
{
    con.close();
}
```

I also added a `finally` block to close the connection, assuming you don't want to use a `using` statement.


You may also want to consider placing the sql execution code in a different function or a completely different class that handles database operations.

Answer (score 1):

your check to see if the `checked` property is `false` is within the scope of the `if` statement for when `checked` is true.

Therefore, it can never be reached. Move it out.

```
private void Submit()
    {
        if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {
            try
            {
               //some stuff
            }
            catch
            {
               //Some other stuff
            }


        }
        if (CheckBox1.Checked == false)
        {
                string script2 = "alert(\"Please Agree to our terms.\");";
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(),
                    "ServerControlScript", script2, true);
        }
    }
```

Or better yet, replace it with an `else`.

Comment: I this one alreay.my checkbox==false message nows function.Now I'm trying to get the output of an exception if my **textbox** is empty.

Answer (score 0):

There are two things as I have observed from your code snippet. That

1. catch is only executed whenever a code block throws error inside from try block. so as @René Vogt has suggested you have to put the

   ```
           cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

           con.Close();
   ```

inside your try block and make the catch block as "catch(SqlException sqex)" and use exception object for exact messages.
2. and secondly remove "CheckBox1.Checked == false" if block and make it in else part of the mail if block.

And test it.